# Flea/tick treatment for senior female cat?

Tags: cats, senior-pet, fleas, ticks

I brought a new male kitty to our apartment, and now my senior citizen female cat has fleas and/or ticks.

What do you recommend for a senior cat? I don't want to use anything harsh that may harm her (ie. secondary side effects).

I'd prefer some drops.

Comment: You should consult your vet for a fitting treatment.

Comment: I'm not putting my 23-year old cat on a cage.

Comment: @rbhat No problem, there are lots of good alternatives for your 23-year old cat to get veterinary care. If a cage or carrier is not doable, then you could try a harness and leash. Or there are vets who can come to your home to provide veterinary care. Or see if your vet will provide telemedicine services.

Comment: Even though a health check is always the safest option, some vets may offer advice or even medication without actually seeing the patient. You should measure your cats weight (for the correct dosage) and try to take a photo of the critters to show your vet. Tics are usually big enough to be very well visible, fleas are much smaller and barely visible to the naked eye. Then simply call your local vet and ask if they will help you.

Comment: Fleas and ticks *are* harmful and can have secondary side effects.